# Unity5 - Overlapping Navmesh areas with different Area Types - is that possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a beach in my game, and at some points the land and water overlap to create shallow water. There are two types of player objects, a car that can only traverse land ("Walkable" Navmesh Area) and a boat that can only traverse water ("Water" Navmesh Area). However, both should be able to traverse these shallow water areas, though the car should stick the the walkable area (generally below the water line) and the boat the water area.

Getting both the Walkable and Water working independently is easy, but right now, all the shallow water areas are seemingly "Water"-only, as my boat can traverse them but the car stops right at the water's edge.

Any tips, solutions, or links to other people who have solved this (my Google-Fu didn't turn up anything) would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I don't understand what is your issue because you can use a height  variable to measure the water level. One last recommendation, you shouldn't overlap Navmeshes because that could lead you to issues/bugs.

Comment: @Cabrra (reference: http://i.imgur.com/zBW4rBW.png)  That's what the pathing should allow. Your suggestion of "use a height variable" is vague, and doesn't provide an obvious solution to the problem; at least one that doesn't present other problems with the navmeshagent. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Of course not. As you know the agent traverses the navmesh. According to your image, the two navmeshes collide. That's the problem; an agent can't go through because it gets locked. I gave you the height variable because is what game developers use. Also the water doesn't exist-> is a post process task (talking C++). Anyway, to solve your issue you should do the following: 1- Put the navmeshes as floors (the water itself shouldn't be a navmesh). 2- Make the ship "float" in the water giving him a sea level height variable. 3- As a prevention check that the ship is colliding with the water.

Comment: 4- Use a height variable for the car which will be water's Y value - Car's Y value (ONLY IF is colliding) 5- If the car is inside the allowed height then he can continue moving (apply movement to the agent). Hope this helps, if not sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: That presents the obvious problem that, without a navmesh or navmeshagent, the ship won't be able to path through the water, avoiding static/dynamic obstacles, unless I roll my own non-navmesh solution.  At that point, there's little reason to use navmesh at all, and use A* with two different path meshes.  (Replying to your edits:  If I'm going manually check "Can I be here? No? Go back to my last position and stop" on every object every frame, and then manually set the height of the boat graphic, that's become more of a hack than a solution.  At that point, I think two A* meshes win.) Thx tho